# Issues updating state in redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following dispatched action:

```
export function fetchUsersForTeam() {
    return {
        type: 'FETCH_USERS_FOR_TEAM__RESOLVED',
        teamId: 123,
        responseData: [
            { userId: 1, name: 'Alice' },
            { userId: 2, name: 'Bob' },
            { userId: 3, name: 'Chris' }, // This is new! "Christopher" is now "Chris"
        ],
    };
};
```

Here is my reducer:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

function getUserById(users, id) {
    return _.find(users, {userId: id});
}

const userServiceReducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'FETCH_USERS_FOR_TEAM__RESOLVED') {
        const userIds = state.usersForTeams[action.teamId];
        const data = action.userData;
        const result = userIds.map(idx => ({
            ...getUserById(state.userData, idx),
            userData: getUserById(action.responseData, idx),
        }));
        console.log(result);

        return result;
    }

    return state;
};

export default userServiceReducer;
```

Here is the initial state:

```
const initState = {
    userData: {
        1: { userId: 1, name: 'Alice' },
        3: { userId: 3, name: 'Christopher' },
        4: { userId: 4, name: 'Dave' },
        5: { userId: 5, name: 'Eliza' },
    },
    usersForTeams: {
        123: [1, 3],
        456: [3, 4, 5],
    },
};
```

The *new* state, after the reducer has done its' thing, should look like the following:

```
const newState = {
    userData: {
        1: { userId: 1, name: 'Alice' },
        3: { userId: 3, name: 'Chris' },
        4: { userId: 4, name: 'Dave' },
        5: { userId: 5, name: 'Eliza' },
    },
    usersForTeams: {
        123: [1, 3],
        456: [3, 4, 5],
    },
};
```

Every time the reducer runs, the return result is an array of objects where each id matches a `userId` from the matched key in the `usersForTeams`.

In the above example, my output is:

```
[{ userId: 1, name: 'Alice' },
{ userId: 3, name: 'Christopher' },]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is you did not merge your new userData to the old state.
Try something like this.

```
function getUserById(users, id) {
    return _.find(users, user => user.userId === id);
}

const userServiceReducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'FETCH_USERS_FOR_TEAM__RESOLVED') {
        const userIds = state.usersForTeams[action.teamId];
        const data = action.userData;
        const newUserData = userIds.map(idx => ({
            ...getUserById(state.userData, idx),
            userData: getUserById(action.responseData, idx),
        }));

        return _.merge({}, state, {userData: newUserData});
    }

    return state;
};
```

Comment: Ah, that works! The one problem I am having now is that none of the new values from the action are applying to any of the user objects. For example. Christopher changed to Chris

Comment: @dennismonsewicz lodash's find function receive predicate function as second parameter(ref: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find)

you should change the way you use find like this.
 _.find(users, user => user.userId === id);